# Conditional record type with FileHelpers

Tags: c#, fixed-width, filehelpers

I'm trying to parse a file using the [Filehelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) library. My file looks like this:

```
000001,"A",123,456
000002,"B","ABC","XYZ"
000003,"B","DEF","XYZ"
000004,"B","HIJ","XYZ"
```

My file contains rows that have different column definitions, where the 'type' of row is defined by the character in the second column. i.e. In the sample above I have an "A" row followed by three "B" rows.

Filehelpers requires that I pass the CLR type used to define a row when I instantiate the file helpers engine, or us the generic version as below.

```
FileHelperEngine<ARecord> engine = new FileHelperEngine<ARecord>()
```

This means I'm restricted to a single type to define every row in my file.
Is there any way I can parse a file like this and conditionally specify the record type based on a part of the given row?

Comment: No idea why this is marked as "unlikely to help".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found it. http://www.filehelpers.com/example_multirecords.html

Comment: Link is broken, but this looks like the same page: https://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultiRecordEngine/